# Evaluate the Limit x approaches 0

Tags: limits

$\displaystyle \lim_{x\to0}  \frac{\sqrt{(x+3)} - \sqrt3} x$

Would I start my multiplying by the conjugate?

$\displaystyle \frac{\sqrt{(x+3)} - \sqrt3}x\times\frac{\sqrt{(x+3)} + \sqrt3}{\sqrt{(x+3)} + \sqrt3}$

Comment: Yes, you would.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, precisely: multiplying numerator and denominator by the conjugate of the numerator works nicely. Now expand the expression you posted, noting that you have a *difference of squares* in the numerator: $$(a - b)(a + b) = a^2 - b^2.$$   Here, you simply have a numerator of the form $\quad(\sqrt a - \sqrt b)(\sqrt a + \sqrt b) = a - b$.

Simplify. You'll find you have a common factor $x$ numerator and denominator which you can cancel.

Evaluating the limit, after canceling that common factor, should then "fall out!"

Answer (score 0):

HINT:

Yes by rationalizing the numerator,

$$\frac{\sqrt{x+3}-\sqrt3}x=\frac{x+3-3}{x(\sqrt{x+3}+\sqrt3)}$$

which is 
$$=\frac1{\sqrt{x+3}+\sqrt3}\text{ if }x\ne0$$

Now, $x\to0\implies x\ne0$

Comment: Wish I know the mistake, here?

Answer (score 0):

Notice:

$$\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\sqrt{x+3}-\sqrt{3}}{x} = \frac{d \sqrt{x}}{dx}|_{x = 3} = \frac{1}{2 \sqrt{3}}$$

I have used the definition of the derivative of a function $f$ at a point $x = x_0 $.

Comment: Why -1 brother ?

Comment: perhaps you should *at least* remark you're applying l'Hospital.